# How to save variable once every time sheet is open in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm running a script using Google Apps Script and the Spreadsheet Service. I created a custom menu using the onOpen() function, and added a button which triggers another function, obtainPriority().

Inside obtain priority I'm doing something time consuming which I realized needs to be done only once for every time someone opens a document. So, I've tried the following code:

```
var priorLists = {};

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Name1')
      .addItem('Name2', 'obtainPriority')
      .addToUi();
  priorLists = doSomethingHeavy();
}
```

and then, in obtain priority:

```
function obtenerPrioridad() {

  /*
  Some code goes here
  */
  var result = randomFunction(priorLists)
  /*
  Some code goes here
  */
}
```

However, randomFunction seems to receive an empty Object. Is this correct? What is the correct way to proceed to define an object only onced and then reuse it?

Comment: Have your consider storing the results in PropertiesService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @cooper, you can use [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties) to save your object. However, please do keep in mind that the `value` associated with the given `key` in the current Properties store should be in type `string`.

### Sample Code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Name1')
      .addItem('Name2', 'obtainPriority')
      .addToUi();
  var priorLists = doSomethingHeavy();
  Logger.log(priorLists);

  //Save the priorLists in the properties service
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var strVal = JSON.stringify(priorLists);
  scriptProperties.setProperty("list", strVal);

}

function doSomethingHeavy(){
  //sample object
  var result = {type:"Fiat", model:"100", color:"white"};
  return result;
}

function obtenerPrioridad() {

  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var priorLists = JSON.parse(scriptProperties.getProperty('list'));
  Logger.log(priorLists);
  Logger.log(typeof priorLists);

}
```

### What it does?

1. Get the script properties using [PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getscriptproperties)
2. Convert `priorLists` object into a string using `JSON.stringify(obj)`.
3. Save the converted string object to the script properties with `key = 'list'` using [setProperty(key, value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setpropertykey,-value)
4. Get the saved string object in the script properties with `key = 'list'` using [getProperty(key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getpropertykey). Then convert the string back to an object using `JSON.parse(str)`

### Output:

```
6:21:03 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:21:04 AM  Info    {type=Fiat, model=100, color=white}
6:21:04 AM  Info    object
6:21:04 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Oh, what a lovely solution! Thanks